# Can't Display Content Following Full-Screen Image Background

Tags: html, css

I'm teaching myself web dev and I created a navbar with full-screen image and background. Now I'm trying to create the following section and/or add text to the image it won't display. I've tried adding height and colour to the section and that works but whenever I add text it doesn't appear. I know it has something to do with the background image because when I comment out the object-fit or position the text appears. Any advice would be appreciated.

The HTML

```
<img class="bg-img" src="./images/marcel-hoy-7lmgkNRfbiE-unsplash.jpg" alt="">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Travel Buddies</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photographs</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimonials</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="features">
    <p>Travel Buddies Features</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus animi non, aliquid illum
        cupiditate, vel nisi mollitia autem, ad facere ipsa quas aspernatur excepturi. Velit accusamus nobiseos
        beatae
        cupiditate.</p>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
   * {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
text-decoration: none;       
}   

ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}   

.navbar {
padding-top: 30px;
}`

.bg-img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  filter: brightness(0.5);
  object-fit: cover; 
  position: absolute;
} 

.navbar-nav a {
font-weight: 400;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1.25em;

.navbar-brand {
font-size: 2em;
}

.features {
height: 500vh;
background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear exactly what is required. Do you want the image to take up space of the viewport (e.g. being seen instead of the aqua color background of the following element) or do you want it to be cut off by the aqua. And do you want it there permanently (when the user scrolls) or is it to scroll with the page?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a typo in your css code: The brace after `.navbar-nav a` is not closed.

You could use `position: relative` and/or `z-index` for `.navbar` and `.features` to get the right order in the stacking context.

c.f.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context